# Loguearse con facebook en Android studio, desloguearse en otra actividad

Tags: android-studio

necesitaría un poco de ayuda. estoy viendo tutoriales para crear un inicio de sesion con facebook en una app con android studio, pero todas las que encuentro, el logueo se hace en la misma actividad, y ese logueo, genera una vez logueado un botón de "deslogueo".

lo que yo necesito es loguearme y ese logueo me haga pasar a otra actividad. y que ese "deslogueo" esté en otra actividad.

pero tiene algunas cosas que no las entendí en su totalidad por eso no logro comprender como genera ese "deslogueo" y como puedo pasarlo a la siguiente actividad.

Este es mi código:

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btnMail;
    private Button btnLogin;
    private Dialog dialogMensaje;
    private EditText edtMail;
    private EditText edtClave;
    private ProgressDialog progress;
    private RequestQueue request;
    private JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private ProfileTracker profileTracker;
    private LoginButton loginButton;






     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

            request = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            btnMail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_logon_mail);
            btnMail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, RegistroMail.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            });

            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

            loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
            loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email","public_profile"));

            // Callback registration
            loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    // App code
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // App code
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    // App code
                }
            });


        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }

        AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken currentAccessToken) {

                if (currentAccessToken != null){

                    loadUserProfile(currentAccessToken);
                }

            }
        };

        private void loadUserProfile(AccessToken newAccessToken){

            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(newAccessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    try {
                        String firstName = object.getString("first_name");
                        String email = object.getString("email");

                        //generar un usuario en la base de datos externa si no existe y traerme el ID.

                        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(Login.this, "Administracion", null, 2);
                        SQLiteDatabase db = admin.getWritableDatabase();
                        db.execSQL("insert into USUARIO (idUsuario, mail, nombre, clave) values (" + 99999 + ", '" +
                                email + "', '" + firstName + "', '" + "facebook" + "')");

                        db.close();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("nombre", firstName);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields","first_name, email");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }


    }
```

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fijate que en el metodo onSuccess del registerCallback para el loginButton (de Facebook) no estas ejecutando ningun codigo.

Ahi es donde deberias hacer el handle del AccessToken que te devuelve Facebook y con eso pegarle a signInWithCredentials (o linkWithCredentials en caso de que estes usando Firebase y el usuario ya exista por ejemplo logueado con Google o Twitter, pero esta ultima parte todavia no la pude hacer funcionar en mi codigo).

```
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        // App code
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
        // App code
    }
});
```

Comment: Gracias! yo ahi modifiqué para q lo haga en success, ahora pasa a otra actividad y ahi meti un boton donde tiene LoginManager.getInstance().logOut(); y eso desloguea el usuario.

pero me quedo feo porque mientras se loguea, hace una verificacion si existe en la BD, y en esos segundos q tarda, se ve como cambia el boton de "Continuar con Facebook" a "Salir" y queda feo, tengo que ver como cambiar eso para que no me cambie el mensaje

le mandé un loginButton.setText("Continuar con Facebook"); pero igual hace el cambio a "salir" y despues me setean nuevamente el continuar.

saludos!

Comment: Pudiste resolverlo? El tema aca entiendo que estas utilizando el facebook login button, que no es muy amigable. Lo ideal que deberias hacer seria tu boton con tus estilos y que en el handler del click, lo que haga sea clickear el boton de facebook para loguearte, que se deberia encontrar invisible. Supongo que no es la mejor forma de hacerlo pero digamos que es lo mas rapido y facil.
Por favor si la respuesta te sirvio marcalo !

Comment: ahi creo que lo arregle poniendo esto en OnSuccess()
if(!loginButton.isInEditMode()){
            loginButton.setLogoutText("Continuar con Facebook");
        }

gracias!